# How to get current day name with jquery

Tags: jquery, date

I am wondering whether it is possible to get the current day name like monday, tuesday, thursday.. with jquery. Is there a kind of plug in or do you even know how to do that?

I build a timetable in which different html files are loaded in via jquery, so the page won't refresh. I want to name the files of the timetable after the day names so that jquery can load it automatically in when the initial page is loaded.

thanks in advance!

Comment: `new Date().getDay();  //0=Sun, 1=Mon, ..., 6=Sat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **jQUery Library** and **jQuery UI library**

#### Check live [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mq4Dg/1/)

#### JQuery

```
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var dayOfWeek = weekday[date.getUTCDay()];
            document.getElementById('datepicker').value = dayOfWeek;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try it! But maybe I need your help. I don't know Jquery

Comment: @JayPatel, It does.. [Is it okay to copy-paste answers from other questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78658/205118)..
Atleast, make some contributions from you end also to the answer..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3e2MW/ This is how my content looks like now. I want the retouched.html to be replaced with the var of the day, so that jquery can load the current day as initial page.